# While running pypi-server getting ValueError: zero length field name in format

Tags: python, linux, pypiserver

Command : pypi-server  -p 8080 -v ~/packages

2017-04-12 10:45:11,939|pypiserver.bottle|INFO|139762541180672|Bottle v0.13-dev server starting up (using AutoServer())...
2017-04-12 10:45:11,939|pypiserver.bottle|INFO|139762541180672|Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
2017-04-12 10:45:11,939|pypiserver.bottle|INFO|139762541180672|Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pypi-server", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pypiserver==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'pypi-server')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pypiserver/__main__.py", line 296, in main
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pypiserver/bottle.py", line 3270, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pypiserver/bottle.py", line 3106, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pypiserver/bottle.py", line 2876, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/waitress-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/waitress/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from waitress.server import create_server
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/waitress-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/waitress/server.py", line 22, in <module>
    from waitress.adjustments import Adjustments
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/waitress-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/waitress/adjustments.py", line 75, in <module>
    class Adjustments(object):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/waitress-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/waitress/adjustments.py", line 116, in Adjustments
    listen = ['{}:{}'.format(host, port)]
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using python 2.6, here you need to explicitly number the format fields.

For python 2.6 you need to change your code `listen = ['{}:{}'.format(host, port)]` to `listen = ['{0}:{1}'.format(host, port)]`

> In python 2.7  '{} {}' is equivalent to '{0} {1}'
>   so in python 2.7 you can use `listen = ['{}:{}'.format(host, port)]`, but not in python 2.6.

Comment: @Michael: have you tried `listen = ['{0}:{1}'.format(host, port)]` in `waitress/adjustments.py`??